# Has xcal been removed from 22.04?

Tags: apt, calendar

Has xcal been removed from 22.04?  I thought it would be around forever :-(

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
% sudo apt-get install xcal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xcal
```

Answer (score 4):

The `xcal` package was dropped from Debian in 2021 after 13 years of dormancy, and subsequently dropped from new releases of Ubuntu.

Reference: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/xcal

Software packages must have an active (upstream) maintainer to address bugs and support queries. Software with dormant or unresponsive upstreams are often removed. When dormant projects revive, the software can be reintroduced.